# How do I know what directories to use for compiling SASS?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I'm new to SASS and needing to compile it into CSS code. I'm using node.js NPM to compile it, I've installed everything and I have my package.json file in the folder for my website. I also have all my CSS and SCSS/SASS files in my website folder, there's no extra folders. I'm following a tutorial and this is the script it uses:

```
"scss": "node-sass --watch assets/scss -o assets/css"
```

Obviously that does not work because the directories `assets/scss` and `assets/css` are wrong. I know I can fix the error by replacing them with the directories of my main.scss file and my main.css file in my website folder. I just don't know what I should write if it's all located in the same folder.

Can anyone tell me how the directories should be written or show me how I should write this script for compiling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your package.json is must in the root directory, so follow it and reach to the destination of your SCSS and CSS folder, I used below node-sass script

```
"node-sass": "node-sass -w --source-map true assets/scss/main.scss assets/css/style.css --output-style expanded"
```

> If it's all located in the same folder

for that, you need to use

```
"node-sass": "node-sass -w --source-map true main.scss style.css --output-style expanded"
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but the latter seems to do nothing when I run the command. My folder looks like this, any ideas?
http://u.cubeupload.com/aperiodicwiseguy/folder.png

Comment: First write some scss in .scss file so it automatically converts into css and here in code scss filename is main.scss and css filename is style.css, remember it